# Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined' Angular error

Tags: angular, properties, undefined, panning

I want as I open a dropdown menu pan to a certain city on the AGM maps. I do this by making this method in the map component, and then calling it from the View:

```
public move = () => {
  alert("Test");
  const position = new google.maps.LatLng(  52.379189,  4.899431);
  this.map.panTo(position);
}
```

However, I get this error message:

> Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined'

Can someone point out what is going wrong?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import {GMapsService} from "./map.service";
import * as data from './inkomen.json';
import * as inbraakdata from '../../assets/output.json';
import * as data_latlon from './inkomen_latlon.json';
import * as inbraak_latlon from './output.json';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {last} from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";
import {DropdownModule} from "ngx-dropdown";
import {any} from "codelyzer/util/function";

@Component({
  selector : 'googlemap',
  templateUrl: 'maps.html',
  styleUrls: ['map.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit{

arr = [];
arr2 = [];

jsonLatlon
map: any;
jsonData
result
inkomen
count = 0;
results: any;
pages =['abc','bca','pqr'];

constructor(private http: Http, private mapservice: GMapsService) {
  this.jsonData = data;
  this.jsonLatlon = data_latlon
  this.results = inbraak_latlon;
  this.result = inbraak_latlon;
}

ngOnInit(){
console.log(this.jsonData)
console.log(this.jsonLatlon.data)
console.log(this.results)
this.convert()


}

convert(){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.jsonData.length; i++){
  var spl = this.jsonData[i].wijk.split(" ");
  // this.getLatLon(this.jsonData[i].wijk, this.jsonData[i].stad, 
  this.jsonData[i].inkomen)
}
//this.showArr()
}





title: string = 'My first AGM project';
lat: number = 52.1941679;
lng: number = 4.6820146;

public move= () => {
  alert("test");
  const position = new google.maps.LatLng(52.379189,  4.899431);
  this.map.panTo(position);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code? Where do you call `move` method?

Comment: post the `map` variable initialization

Comment: You didn't gave a value to `data`, so it's `undefined`

Comment: Done @SachilaRanawaka

Comment: And @yurzui     ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map should be initialized to have the method .map, since you are already using **`@agm/core`** you cane make use of **`GoogleMapsAPIWrapper`**

import

```
import { AgmCoreModule, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, AgmInfoWindow, AgmDataLayer, CircleManager, AgmCircle } from '@agm/core';
```

and refer

```
 @ViewChild(GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) private gmapWrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper;
```

and you can do

**`this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);`**

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still the same error message

Comment: yes, and called it by this: <div class="dropdown" dropdown [dropdownToggle]="false" (onOpen)="move()"

Comment: i think onOpen is getting called before the map gets initialized, debug and see

Comment: I moved the markup of the call below the agm map, and now I get this error message:  Argument of type 'LatLng' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLng | LatLngLiteral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161749/discussion-between-user3660293-and-sajeetharan).